# How to get the static libraries available in an android .so file

Tags: shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have an android .so(example.so) file which is build with some n number of static libraries(.a files). Is there is any way to find what are the static libraries used to built that .so(example.so) file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to figure out which static libraries were used to build the shared library. Shared libraries aren't a container of their components like static libraries are, but are a linked form of all the object files.

I think the best you can do here is figure out which source files are included, and only if the library hasn't been stripped. You can use `readelf -sW libfoo.so`, and if it was built from foo.cpp you'll see:

```
    ...
    18: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS foo.cpp
    ...
```